# have a speed issue with two websites

Tags: website, speed

Two websites I manage https://www.wisepelican.com/ and https://www.kay-grant.com/ Are having speed issues. Wise pelican is a wordpress site that utilizes Divi builder and Kay-Grant Group is built on the real geeks platform for which I don't have back end access to. Which plugins work well in conjunction with Divi without breaking the site and is there another way to affect speed without having back end access or being able to serve images in next gen formats?